# When I am trying to connect to Oracle Database Through Spring Batch using Spring Datasource i am getting Error for metadata table

Tags: spring-batch

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? order by JOB_INSTANCE_ID desc]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: maybe you don't have access and/or you need to define the schema. Take a look at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/63771-badsqlgrammarexception-running-commandlinejobrunner

Comment: I am able to access the database through jpa in the same project so i think access is not the issue , and i am using the spring starter project for creating spring batch configuration so i am not aware how i could define the default table schema and all.

Comment: Ask DBA set default schema for the user name you are using to connect to DB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may need to edit you xml config file

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager" 
  p:tablePrefix="MYDB.BATCH_"/>
```

MYDB been your schema
[Source](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/63771-badsqlgrammarexception-running-commandlinejobrunner)

Comment: I am not using xml config file as i am using the spring starter project with spring Batch configuration. Is there any other approach i could use ?